# How to sort the words based on count value: javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Need to print the input String in Ascending order based on the number of words count. 
I tried this piece of code!

> **My question is**, How to sort the elements based on `count` value ? i.e. greater `count` value word should be displayed first (descending order of `count` value)?

Javascript file, `app.js`:

```
var x = stringCount("this is my file teting the things apple teting this is my the is is is is ", ' ');
console.log(x);

function stringCount(haystack, needle) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var words = haystack.split(needle),
            count = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (count.hasOwnProperty(words[i])) {
                count[words[i]] = parseInt(count[words[i]], 10) + 1;
            }
            else {
                count[words[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
        count.sort();
        return count;

    }
}
```

This is the **output** what I'm getting.

```
[ this: 2,
  is: 6,
  my: 2,
  file: 1,
  teting: 2,
  the: 2,
  things: 1,
  apple: 1,
  '': 1 ]
```

Comment: This is unclear question. What elements and what kind of object do you want to sort? Provide input and desired output.

Comment: i get no output.

Comment: Why don't you just get the length of the array (the count of words in the sentence), and based on that number, provide a > or < to the sort?

Comment: `words.sort((a,b) => a > b)); //or < if opposite`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
    return count;
```

to:

```
    return Object.keys(count).map(k => [k, count[k]])
        .sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1]).map(e => e[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` variable is an object. Although you defined it as an array, it has not real array elements, but word-properties. So you are actually sorting an empty array.

Here is how you could adapt your code to make it work:

```js
var x = stringCount("this is my file teting the things apple teting this is my the is is is is ", ' ');
console.log(x);

function stringCount(haystack, needle) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var words = haystack.split(needle).filter(x => x), // filter out empty words
            count = {}; // not an array
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (count.hasOwnProperty(words[i])) {
                count[words[i]] = parseInt(count[words[i]], 10) + 1;
            }
            else {
                count[words[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
        return Object.keys(count) // array of words
                .sort( (a,b) => count[b] - count[a] ); // sort by count
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the keys by the values.

```js
function stringCount(haystack, needle) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    var words = haystack.split(needle),
        count = {};
    words.forEach(function (a) {
        count[a] = (count[a] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return count;
}

var x = stringCount("this is my file teting the things apple teting this is my the is is is is ", ' ');

console.log(x);
console.log(Object.keys(x).sort(function (a, b) { return x[b] - x[a]; }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```